# How to put info of a text file in a tuple to be convertible to SQL table?

Tags: python, mysql

I have several text files that contain specific information.I need to extract the required info from the files and put them in a MySQL table. The files contain several lines  of info but I only need these three lines for instance:

```
Name:      Gorge
Registration ID: 6657
Registration Time:  2012-09-10 14:31:13
```

I wrote the below code but the result of the code is not what I want. The code still do not contain the insert for SQL part.

```
import fnmatch
import os
import pprint



matches=[]
b=[]

for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('d:/Data'):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, 'Info_reg.txt'):
        matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))


all_keys = ['name','Registration ID','registration time']
for m in matches:
    f=open(m,'r')
    for line in f:        
        for n in all_keys:
            if line.startswith(n):
                a = line.split(':',1)
                b.append(a)
```

and the code result is like below which I assume cannot easily convert to a table:

```
['registration time', '     2012-10-08 17:28:47\n'],
 ['Registration ID', ' 9876'],
 ['Name', '      Malcom\n'],

 ['registration time', '     2012-10-08 17:28:47\n'],
 ['Registration ID', ' 45'],
 ['Name',      'mazu\n'],
```

Does anyone have an idea how can I change my code to make a nice table out of this file?

Comment: What Python MySQL driver are you using?

Comment: Do the lines always appear in the same order? Is there anything to delineate one record from the next, like an empty line, or a record always starts with the `Registration ID` key, for example.

Comment: Yes there are always in the same order and they start with a word

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to call `.strip()` on the results, and store the whole thing in a dictionary instead of a list of lists.

We can also optimize the line search and record handling; I am assuming here that when we find a `Name` entry a new record has started:

```
records = []

all_keys = {'Name', 'Registration ID', 'registration time'}
first_key = 'Name'

for m in matches:
    with open(m, 'r') as f
        record = dict.fromkeys(all_keys)  # new record dictionary with `None` values

        for line in f:
            key, value = line.split(':', 1)
            key, value = key.strip(), value.strip()
            if key not in all_keys:
                continue  # not interested in this line

            if key == first_key and any(v for v in record.itervalues()):
                # new record, finalize the previous
                records.append(record)
                record = dict.fromkeys(all_keys)

            record[key] = value

        if any(v for v in record.itervalues()):
            # there is something in the last record still, add that too
            records.append(record)
```

Now you have a list of records of the form:

```
records = [
    {'registration time', '2012-10-08 17:28:47', 'Registration ID': '9876', 'Name', 'Malcom'},
    {'registration time', '2012-10-08 17:28:47', 'Registration ID': '45', 'Name', 'mazu'},
]
```

These can be inserted into a database with MySQLdb using `.executemany()` in one go:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO sometable (id, name, time) VALUES (%(Registration ID)s, %(Name)s, %(registration time)s)',
    records)
conn.commit()
```

This inserts all collected records straight into the database.

Comment: @ Martijn Pieters thanks for the answer it totally helped. Could you please tell me also what should I do if I want to add the file name of each file to the list? so the columns be filename, name,id,time?

Comment: @user2058811: just add it to the records: `record['file'] = m` right after each `record = dict.fromkeys(all_keys)` line. Don't forget to insert the `file` value into the database too. :-)

Comment: @ Martijn Pieters I get this error when I run the code :if key == first_key and any(value in record.itervalues()):
TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable

Comment: @user2058811: My apologies, the generator expression wasn't complete.

Comment: @ Martijn Pieters when I am trying to convert the data into a sql table I get this error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\samounk\workspace\Thesis\Realdata\Datasets 1\MyTable_info.py", line 63, in <module>
    records)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 245, in executemany
    self.errorhandler(self, TypeError, msg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
TypeError: float argument required, not dict

Comment: @user2058811: Interesting; `dict` implies that you have nested dictionaries. Can you give me a sample `record`?

Comment: @user2058811: `records[0]` would be the first record you generated; that'd be a sample of what you created. :-)

Comment: {'Registration time': '2012-09-12 12:48:17',
 'Registration time UTC': '2012-09-12 10:48:17',
 'name': 'gorge',
 'registration id': '589',
 'file_name': ('1', '0')}

Comment: @user2058811: `file_name` there looks odd, that is a `tuple()`, not a string. You'd need to investigate why that is. Other than that this does look correct. Let me check something first.

Comment: @user2058811: did you use `%(file_name)f` perhaps? You need to use `%(file_name)s` instead; the MySQLdb adapter re-uses the Python string formatting syntax here, but all interpolated values are strings.

Answer (score 1):

This may inspire a solution:

```
data = '''\
Name:      Gorge
Registration ID: 6657
Registration Time:  2012-09-10 14:31:13
Somethign else: foo
Spam:   Bar
Name:      mazu
Registration ID: 45
Registration Time:  2012-10-08 17:28:47
Somethign else: foo
Spam:   Bar'''.split('\n')

records = []
titles = ['Name','Registration ID','Registration Time']

def record_is_complete(rec):
    return (rec.get('Name')
            and rec.get('Registration ID')
            and rec.get('Registration Time'))

def make_tuple(rec):
    result = [ rec[key] for key in titles ]
    return tuple(result)

record = {}
for line in data:
    key, value = line.split(':', 1)
    if key in titles:
        record[key] = value.strip()
    if record_is_complete(record):
        records.append(make_tuple(record))
        record = {}

print records
```

Result:

```
[('Gorge', '6657', '2012-09-10 14:31:13'), 
 ('mazu', '45', '2012-10-08 17:28:47')]
```